Why is the reliability of Stormy Daniels testimony relevant in Trump's hush money process?
As I understand, the issue here is that Trump falsified his account to cover the payment, not that he assaulted Daniels.
Why is Daniels' (or McDougals') testimony from May 7&9 relevant? Whatever happened between the two, it's not relevant to whether Trump falsified his accounts.

The charge is not a plain fraud charge. The offence becomes a felony when the "intent to defraud includes an intent to commit another crime or to aid or conceal the commission thereof." Prosecutors have revealed that one option they are advancing for the "another crime" is New York State Election Law Section 17-152, which makes it an offence for two or more persons to conspire to promote or prevent the election of any person to a public office by unlawful means.
The theory of relevance, proposed by various commentators, like Roger Parloff at Lawfare (see the May 7 podcast episode: listen to minutes 19 through 22) is that because this charge is also about influencing an election by illegal means, it is important for the jury to understand what was being suppressed by the payments (documentation about which was allegedly falsified).
The prosecution team submitted during the May 7 mistrial hearing that Daniels's evidence is highly probative of Trump's intent.
The prosecution also drew out evidence from Daniels that may show that Mr. Trump did not care about keeping Daniels's story secret until after he became a candidate for the Presidency.

IOW, it's not only important that he falsified the accounts, but why he did it, since that changes it from a misdemeanor to a felony.

The other relevant factor is that Trump's lawyer, during opening statements, claimed that the encounter between Trump and Daniels never took place at all. That opens the door to very specific testimony about the encounter itself, since the prosecution has to establish that Daniels is a credible witness (and Trump's lawyer has now accused her of lying). If the defense had instead stipulated to the encounter having taken place as Daniels says it did, then it is likely that her testimony would have been much less salacious, because they would not be allowed to belabor the point.

Just to see if I understand this right: allegedly, Trump had an extramarital affair with Stormy Daniels which, if it became well-known, is expected to damage his 2016 presidential campaign. Therefore he paid hush money to Stormy Daniels, which he allegedly falsified. If he only falsified his accounts, it would be a misdemeanor only (which is a lesser crime). The prosecution is claiming that Trump committed that misdemeanor because he wanted to promote his own campaign by concealing this information, and concealing harmful information is unlawful.

Meanwhile, the defense is claiming that the encounter never happened, therefore there is no falsification in the accounts?

@Allure As I understand it, the idea that there wasn't any issue with the accounts is a separate thing. If his lawyers can take that out, everything else goes away. But if they can't, that angle of defense is that even if falsification of accounts happened, they're trying to show that the felony of concealing information didn't happen. They're covering bases.

@Graham why would it be sufficient to prove that the encounter between Trump and Daniels never happened? If she intended to allege that it did and the payment served to induce her not to make such a public allegation then it surely has exactly the same status in terms of election law.

@Will: Consider two scenarios: (1) Donald Trump pays a radio station to present him in an falsely positive light, but routes the payment via MC to avoid campaign finance disclosures; (2) A radio station threatens to present DT in an unfairly negative light unless he gives them money; MC pays them, in exchange for which their coverage will be neutral.  Technically, both would be campaign finance violations, but a jury would likely perceive a greater degree of criminal intent in the former case than the latter, and thus be more likely to convict.

The Judge himself actually answered this question at the end of yesterday's session. This is Trump's lawyers own doing.
At the beginning of the trial they decided (one suspects at their client's insistence) to dispute that Ms. Daniel's account of events ever happened at all. So while her credibility might not necessarily have been at issue here, the Defense chose to made it so.
Here's how Judge Merchan put it ("Mr. Blanche" is Trump's lead counsel):

Mr. Blanche in your opening statement, you denied there was ever a
sexual encounter between your defendant and Stormy Daniels.
Your denial puts the jury in a position of having to choose who they
believe: Donald Trump, who denies that there was an encounter, or
Stormy Daniels, who claims that there was.
The more specificity Daniels provides the better that can weigh her
credibility.

... and in conclusion ...

You said, "My client never had a sexual encounter": that pits
your client against Ms. Daniels. So the prosecution can rehabilitate
her credibility.
YOUR MOTION FOR A MISTRIAL IS DENIED. I’LL SEE YOU TOMORROW AT 9:30


Defense really shot itself in the foot here, probably at Trump's insistence.  Not stipulating to the occurrence of the sexual encounter means there's a disagreement on relevant facts that can be argued in court before the jury, and attacking a witnesses credibility in the opening statement means the prosecution gets to rehab that credibility and seek more details.  And Merchan also chided the defense for not objecting to these things while they were happening if they had such a problem with it.

He didn't use s handgun to shoot his foot, the foot is but a bloody mess turned pulp by all the shoddy lawyering and client interference against his own interests.  Client control does not work...

Normally I'd pity his lawyers (Is it still Habba? Or did she get replaced by someone else?) but at this point they have to have known what kind of an clown he was well before they agreed to take his case, so...

My (generous?) take on it is that their client feels, perhaps not without justification, that the political/reputational threat is the bigger long-term danger to himself, and to best mitigate the damage there he needs to not admit to anything. Even if the jury trivially finds otherwise, he can claim bias and whatnot and still play innocent victim. His own personal image management is something he's an expert at, while he can leave his legal experts to do their best in the legal sphere with whatever is left to them to do.

It is not. The goal of the procecuters is to convince the jury that the misdemeanors lead to the felony. Only then can their case be won.
A comment I made to others after the first half of that days procedings:

The procecuters have proven their point, then (during the 2016 election) and now (2024) the Trump 'crew' have undertaken great efforts to prevent the conservative voters from learning the details of the 2006 'meeting' with Stormy Daniels. So the motive is clear. We will later see if the jury see this in the same way.

(Originaly posted as a comment that was later deleted and received 4 upvotes: Comment from 2024-05-11)


2024-05-09 BBC: Trump trial: What we learned from Stormy Daniels' testimony
Building a 'narrative'
With their cross-examination, Mr Trump's legal team also may have inadvertently helped the prosecution's case, experts said.
While grilling Ms Daniels, the defence demonstrated exactly why Mr Trump would have tried to conceal the sex scandal before the election - to avoid association with a witness the defence team portrayed as ''tawdry,'' Ms Florence said.
"It was a side show at the trial - and it would've been a main event just before the election," she said.

